# How to add missing kernel modules into xenserver using DDK?

Tags: linux, xenserver

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, stackoverflow doesn't seem quite right... anyway, maybe someone has done this before here.

I would like to add some missing kernel modules into my XenServer installs to support infiniband HCA's. Since I'll be deploying more of these I would like to create a supplemental pack using the provided XenServer 6.2 DDK.

These kernel modules are not new sources but come with the standard Linux Kernel source tree. They are just not compiled in by default into the Dom0 Xen kernel in XenServer 6.2.

The current kernel source is already on there under /usr/src/kernels.

But there don't seem to be any examples that show how to build specific kernel modules from the sources that are already under /usr/src/ and which ones to place into the supplemental pack that you want to build.

How do I go about doing this so? I want to be able to run IPoIB basically.